Find a sequence polynomials that converges to $e^{x-y}$ on $S^1$ but diverge anywhere else
I'm trying to do Exercise 3.3.1 in scv.pdf

Let $z=x+i y$ as usual in $\mathbb{C}$. Find a sequence of polynomials in $x$ and $y$ that converge uniformly to $e^{x-y}$ on $S^1$, but diverge everywhere else.

I think $e^{x-y}$ can be written as a holomorphic function in the annulus $1-ϵ<|z|<1+ϵ$
$$\exp(x-y)=\exp\left(\frac{1+i}2(x+iy)+\frac{1-i}{2}(x-iy)\right)=\exp\left(\frac{1+i}2\cdot z+\frac{1-i}{2}\cdot z^{-1}\right)$$
its Laurent series converges uniformly on compact sets in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.
but this doesn't satisfy the requirement "diverge everywhere else".

From the proof of Weierstrass theorem on $[−1, 1]$:
Normalizing $P_n=\left(1-x^2\right)^n$, put $p_n=\frac{P_n}{\|P_n\|_{L^1[-1,1]}}$.
By “differentiating under the integral sign”, we have$$
D^j\left(f * p_n\right)=(-1)^j f * D^j\left(p_n\right)
$$
so that for each $n$, the $j^{\text {th}}$ derivative of $f * p_n$ is identically zero for $j$ sufficiently large. Hence $f * p_n$ is polynomial.

Which holomorphic function should I convolve with $e^{x-y}$ on $S^1$?

I think you over complicate - just take $2P_n(x,y)=((x^2+y^2)^n+(2-x^2-y^2)^n)\sum_{k\le n}(x-y)^k/k!$
